# while calling Api in retrofit facing issue

Tags: android, api, retrofit

While calling this API in retrofit facing issue apply "/" i also tried this by applying "/" in end like this but doesnt work. Please suggest anything.

For example: http://137.116.113.179/xyz/LoginService.svc/FetchAllData?companyid=3457&AppVersion=3.7.4

Comment: Share your code what you have tried and error log?

Answer (score 0):

it maybe issue from server side If you hit that url in chrome you are getting same error instead of data

If not then you are using base url without "/" in the end.
so baseUrl should be like

either "https://stackoverflow.com"

or "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/"

Comment: No its not server issue i haven't paste exact url its just an example of issue."
Main issue
While calling this api in retrofit facing issue apply "/" i also tried this by applying "/" in end like this but doesnt work"

Comment: can you add here both URl that you are using

Comment: With this url "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos" if i put / on end it gives 404 error else give baseUrl must end with "/".

Comment: for above example baseurl should be this either "https://api.github.com" or "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/"

If you are using "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray" using like this then it will give error